# Need help writing data from a table in R for unique values using a loop

Tags: r, for-loop

Trying to figure why when I run this code all the information from the columns is being written to the first file only. What I want is only the data from the columns unique to a MO number to be written out. I believe the problem is in the third line, but am not sure how to divide the data by each unique number.

Thanks for the help,

---

```
for (i in 1:nrow(MOs_InterestDF1)) {

MO = MOs_InterestDF1[i,1]

df =  MOs_Interest[MOs_Interest$MO_NUMBER == MO, c("ITEM_NUMBER", "OPER_NO", "OPER_DESC", "STDRUNHRS", "ACTRUNHRS","Difference", "Sum")]

submit.df <- data.frame(df)

filename = paste("Variance", "Report",MO, ".csv", sep="")

write.csv(submit.df, file = filename, row.names = FALSE)}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to write out a separate csv for each unique MO number, then something like this may work to accomplish that.

```
unique.mos <- unique(MOs_Interest$MO_NUMBER)

for (mo in unique.mos){

  submit.df <- MOs_Interest[MOs_Interest$MO_NUMBER == mo, c("ITEM_NUMBER", "OPER_NO", "OPER_DESC", "STDRUNHRS", "ACTRUNHRS","Difference", "Sum")]

  filename <- paste("Variance", "Report", mo, ".csv", sep="")

  write.csv(submit.df, file = filename, row.names = FALSE)
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to answer fully without example data (what are the columns of `MOs_InterestDF1`?) but I think your issue is in the df line. Are you trying to subset the dataframe to only the data matching the MO? If so, try `which` as in `df =  MOs_Interest[which(MOs_Interest$MO_NUMBER == MO),]`.

I wasn't sure if you actually had two separate dfs (`MOs_Interest` and `MOs_InterestDF1`); if not, make sure the `df` line points to the correct data frame.

I tried to create some simplified sample data:

```
MOs_InterestDF1 <- data.frame("MO_NUMBER" = c(1,2,3), "Item_No" = c(142,423,214), "Desc" = c("Plate","Book","Table"))
for (i in 1:nrow(MOs_InterestDF1)) {
MO = MOs_InterestDF1[i,1]
mydf = data.frame(MOs_InterestDF1[which(MOs_InterestDF1$MO_NUMBER == MO),])
filename = paste("This is number ",MO,".csv", sep="")
write.csv(mydf, file = filename, row.names=FALSE)
}
```

This output three different csv files, each with exactly one row of data. For example, "This is number 1.csv" had the following data:

```
MOs Item_No   Desc
1     142     Plate
```

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, MOs_InterestDF1 was a table of the unique values, and the MOs_Interest had all the information. Poor choice of titles on my part.